# Remove thousand point in type="number" in HTML5 on iPad

Tags: ipad, html

I use an input field of the type number so the iPad would bring up the numeric keypad automatically.

But when I fill up the field and display it, it shows a thousand point on the iPad, in Chrome it does not.

Is there any way to remove that thousand point ? Using CSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type="tel"` instead of `type="number"`